# Node-Red - catching HTTP 401 error with Catch Error node

Tags: exception, node-red

I'm using Request Node to send a POST request, response is 401, I'm getting response in the Debug Node which is logging the response but the Catch Error node not catching the error

Flow is as follow:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the "Only send non-2xx responses to Catch node" box in the http-request node?

Comment: @hardillb, I tested both Checked and Unchecked, but didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a switch node after the http-request node to test on the `msg.statusCode` rather than a catch node